# How can I get the User nodes in Drupal database in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, drupal

I am using a headless CMS, with Drupal and React. I am getting the node entities (content), but I want to get the list of users and their roles, but I can't seem to get the correct endpoint.

I am using Axios and I followed this guide to connect React to the backend.

https://www.drupalgovcon.org/2018/program/sessions/reactjs-headless-drupal-step-step

I have enabled Rest Web Services and a headless module supplied by the video above. I have tried the endpoints of ('users'), but that isn't returning me anything.

```
 try {
     const axios = await ajax() 
     const response = await axios.get('/users') // wait for the POST AJAX request to complete
     if (response.data) {
       this.setState({ nodes: response.data })
     }
     } catch (e) {
     alert(e)
   }
```

Comment: "I am using a headless CMS, with Drupal"...this is confusing... Are you using Drupal as the CMS? or something else? You reference a "module supplied by the video above", do you expect people to watch the whole video to try to help you? The JSON API module has just landed in Drupal Core, it may be easier to use that instead of restful web services module.

Comment: Also, "but that isn't returning me anything". Are you sure of this? It's not returning a response code, or an empty array? Check in the browser console.